# jQuery on click not working on division with same classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, this

**EDIT**

I have let's say 50 divisions, all with the class .tablestyle
Id like to see if I click a specific division but still with class .tablestyle execute the my animation.

If I want to execute the animation only on the first division it is easy:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tablestyle").first().on("click", function() {
        $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);
    });
});
```

but I also like to execute another animation on divisions 2 till 5.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tablestyle").secondtillfive???().on("click", function() {
            $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);
        });
    });
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: please share html code also

Comment: Inside `$(document).ready(function() {` `this` refers not to your `div`s.

Comment: Try $('.tablestyle').on('click'.... instead of $(this) which is the window object, and since you're just targeting the closest '.tablestyle' it wont trigger on all of them.

Comment: In this case all divisions with class .tablestyle will execute my animation. Only the division I click on must execute this animation!

Comment: Its not clear what you want?

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan you execute animation for static element, selected by ID. What does _Only the division I click on must execute this animation_ mean at all?

Comment: For example the first division with class .tablestyle has to execute another animation then 2nd to 5th divisions.

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan then use `$(this).find('.element_to_animate').animate({left: 0}, 600);` inside `click` event handler.

Comment: See my edit above pls

Comment: I think you need `$(".tablestyle:lt(5)").on("click", function() { ...` http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: Yes!! And with an interval? Like division 3 to 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tablestyle:lt(5)").on("click.animate", function() { //Bind event for less than 5
        $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);
        $(this).off("click.animate"); //Remove click handler, thus used namespace event handler
    });
});
```

*Updated Code*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function eventHandler() { 
        //Animate
        $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);

        //Remove click handler, thus used namespace event handler
        $(".tablestyle").off("click.animate"); 

        //Get Index
        var index = $(".tablestyle").index( this );

        //Bind event for interval Index less than 5
        $(".tablestyle:gt(" + index +"):lt(5)").on("click.animate", eventHandler);            
    }

    //Bind event for greater than 1 less than 5
    $(".tablestyle:gt(1):lt(5)").on("click.animate", eventHandler);
});
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, but how does it work with an interval? Like division 3 to 5? something like :lt(3>5) ?

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan `$(".tablestyle:gt(1):lt(5)")`

Answer (score 0):

`closest` goes up finding precedents. `document` is a root element. So, there can't be any precendent to it. So change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tablestyle").on("click", function() {
        $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case all divisions with class .tablestyle will execute my animation. Only the division I click on must execute this animation!

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan do you have any special thing to indicate which divs can be clicked?

Comment: Let's say .first() executed a kind of animation but. 2nd till 5th division executes another animation?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tablestyle").first().on("click", function() {
        $("#advertentieorchidee").animate({left: 0}, 600);
    });
});
```

Note: remove `.first()` if you want to bind the click event to the whole `.tablestyle` collection.

Comment: @Regent because he used `.closest()` - and closest gets the first element that matches the selector.

Comment: This will end up that only my first division will execute the animation? but what if I click on my third division with class .tablestyle?

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan then remove `.first()` bit - you will bind the click event for all `.tablestyle` elements.

Comment: I like the .first() but is there a way to count? So let's say .first() executed a kind of animation but. 2nd till 5th division executes another animation?

Comment: @martynas original `$(this).closest(".tablestyle")` has no sense at all, don't forget about it.

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan count what, sorry? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan once again: you execute animation for static `$("#advertentieorchidee")` element, selected by ID. Right now you have **one** animated element for all `.tablestyle`

Comment: @KevinAmmerlaan you really need to prepare a jsFiddle.